# put white spaces when entering an amount moneytype symfony

Tags: jquery, symfony-forms

I would like to put spaces when entering an amount like this. Do I have to use javascript?
Thank you for your help me[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAYLy.png)

Answer (score 1):

Yes if you are creating the program on the browser using html and js, you can use the following code to achieve it. By changing the template inside `amountInput.oninput` you can change the maximum amount.

HTML

```
<label>Montant Rechargement</label>
<br />
<input
  autocomplete="cc-number"
  id="amountInput"
  name="amountInput"
  type="tel"
  placeholder="1 000 000"
/>
```

JS

```
const amountInput = document.getElementById("amountInput");

amountInput.oninput = (e) => {
  let cursorPos = e.target.selectionStart
  let currentValue = e.target.value
  let cleanValue = currentValue.replace(/\D/g, "");
  let formatInput = patternMatch({
      input: cleanValue,
      template: "x xxx xxx xxx"
   });
  
  e.target.value = formatInput
  
  let isBackspace = (e?.data==null) ? true: false
  let nextCusPos = nextDigit(formatInput, cursorPos, isBackspace)
  
  amountInput.setSelectionRange(nextCusPos+1, nextCusPos+1);
};

function nextDigit(input, cursorpos, isBackspace) {
  if (isBackspace){
    for (let i = cursorpos-1; i > 0; i--) {
    if(/\d/.test(input[i])){
      return i
    }
  }
  }else{
    for (let i = cursorpos-1; i < input.length; i++) {
    if(/\d/.test(input[i])){
      return i
    }
  }
  }
  
  return cursorpos
}

function patternMatch({
  input,
  template
}) {
  try {

    let j = 0;
    let plaintext = "";
    let countj = 0;
    while (j < template.length) {
      // code block to be
      
      if (countj > input.length - 1) {
        template = template.substring(0, j);
        break;
      }

      if (template[j] == input[j]) {
        j++;
        countj++;
        continue;
      }

      if (template[j] == "x") {
        template = template.substring(0, j) + input[countj] + template.substring(j + 1);
        plaintext = plaintext + input[countj];
        countj++;
      }
      j++;
    }

    return template
 
  } catch {
    return ""
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow thank you very much it works well, you save my life. thank you very much. What if I wanted to have a number like this 3 00 000 000 ?

Comment: I have a numbertype in php symfony and this is not taken into account during validation

Comment: See line number 9 in the JS code inside `amountInput.oninput`. Change the template with this: 

template: "x xx xxx xxx"